# ASP.NET Core with Winforms - Saving the username once

Tags: winforms, asp.net-core, .net-core, webserver

I have a standard Hoemcontroller in ASP.NET Core MVC:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index(string user)
        {
            if(user != null)
            {
                TempData["UserName"] = user;
                return View("Index", user);
            }
            return View("Index");
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
```

In the Index Action there will be a parameter sent from a winforms application. The string will contain the username of the client connecting to the website. This is the code for winforms:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChromium();
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }

        public void InitializeChromium()
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
            Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
            chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://localhost:5001/Home/Index/" + Environment.UserName);
            this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
            //chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Cef.Shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Now I am unsure on how to handle this on the webserver. I get the username inside the HomeController but in the same time when a user goes to the other pages with their controllers then the user should see only his content. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to do authorization through a parameter in URI. For that, you should use Authentication (when the user passes his login and password) and receive a token with permissions. After that, you pass the token to the server and check permission there(using `Authorize` attribute for example). [Example](https://weisong0908.medium.com/simple-authentication-and-authorisation-in-asp-net-core-web-api-6c8ad87ce534)

If you are making a test project, and you don't need authentication at all, then you can pass a username everywhere you need and write some code to handle the content of every user (using headers, URI parameters, etc.)

Comment: The program is made internally for a company so only user inside the company can access the site. But they dont want a login thats the problem here you know. I could use ms authentication with azure and so on but they dont want that. They basically want to enter the site and see their stuff without logging in

Comment: So, the program is available only from company PCs?

Comment: In that case, to bypass your restriction, you could have a look at Client Credential flow (https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/client-credentials-flow) and authorize your app only. But it's not secure either as you save a secret on the client app and it could be stolen.